# Django query with Q filter _lte on DateField (USE_TZ=True) doesn't work (MySql DB)

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset

I got an **Invoice** model with a field `created_at` as **models.DateTimeField()** with a few records containing several dates:

[image]

With an HTML form, I want to filter by dates

```
<input name="start" class="form-control me-3" type="date" value="{{ min_date|date:'Y-n-d' }}" />
```

I got the same field for **end date** and when I print them in my view, they seem to be in the correct format `2023-11-12 -> 2023-11-17`.

In my view, I check if the two fields contain values and if yes, I filter my **Invoice** queryset:

I tried lotsa combinations for queryset filtering and every time, the **__lte** clause seems not to work correctly and results don't include my **end** date. `__lt` is applied instead of  `__lte`. Among those combinations I tried :

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # limit records number if no filter
        invoices = Invoice.objects.all()[:100]
        
    else:
        start = request.POST.get('startDate')
        end = request.POST.get('endDate')
        invoices = Invoice.objects.all()
        if start:
            invoices = invoices.filter(created_at__gte=start)
        if end:
            invoices = invoices.filter(created_at__lt=end)
```

also tried :

```
[...]    
    else:
        start = request.POST.get('start')
        end = request.POST.get('end')
        if start and end:
            invoices = invoices.filter(
                Q(created_at__gte=start) & Q(created_at__lte=end))
        if end and not start:
            invoices = invoices.filter(Q(created_at__lte=end))
        if not end and start:
            invoices = invoices.filter(Q(created_at__gte=start))
```

First, I thought it was due to the warning about `("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)` and even with `make_aware`, the problem remains. And I tried to rebuild the base queryset on each line.

```
    else:
    start = request.POST.get('start')
    end = request.POST.get('end')
    tz_start = make_aware(datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    tz_end = make_aware(datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    if not start and end:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(Q(created_at__lte=tz_end))
    elif start and end:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(
            Q(created_at__gte=tz_start) & Q(created_at__lte=tz_end))
    elif start and not end:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(
            Q(created_at__gte=tz_start))
    else:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.all()
        messages.error(request, 'no filter applied')
```

Is it such a big thing I'm missing that I even can't see it ?

Comment: Even with using **django_filters**, I got the same problem. Tried also to reimport fresh datas, same issue. The "equal" isn't applied in **less than or equal** filter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no relation between this issue ans MySql, or timezone, or nothing else relating to the environment.

After 3 days trying to find a solution, [this page](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters/issues/125#issuecomment-372189983) put me on the good path

I don't know if my issue was because I was trying to compare Date input with a DateTimeField of my model, or maybe if this kind of anomaly is specific to date filtering with **django_filters** , but finally, **django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter** saved my day (should I say, my week). With 3x less code, my view now works.

**filter.py**

```
import django_filters
from websales.models import Invoice


class InvoiceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    created_at = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(
        field_name='created_at',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ['created_at']
```

**views.py**

```
def invoices_with_filter(request):
    invoice_filter = InvoiceFilter(request.GET, queryset=Invoice.objects.all())
    context = {}

    max_min = invoice_filter.qs.aggregate(Min(
        'created_at'), Max('created_at'))
    context['max_date'] = max_min['created_at__max']
    context['min_date'] = max_min['created_at__min']
    context['invoices'] = invoice_filter.qs
    context['form'] = invoice_filter.form
    if invoice_filter.qs.count() == 0:
        messages.error(request, 'Aucune donnée correspondant aux filtres !')
    return render(request, 'websales/invoices.html', context=context)
```

And for those who want to **boostrap5** easily the form in the template (it also took me time to find the way), just take the names of the **invoice_filter.form**'s inputs as below : `created_at_before` and `created_at_after`

```
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'websales:invoices' %}" class="row gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center mb-4">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-text" id="start">Début</div>
                <input name="created_at_before" class="form-control me-3" type="date"
                    value="{{ min_date|date:'Y-n-d' }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto me-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-text" id="end">fin</div>
                <input name="created_at_before" class="form-control" type="date" value="{{ max_date|date:'Y-n-d' }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-success me-3" role="submit">Filtrer</button>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary me-3" role="button" href="{% url 'websales:invoices' %}">Reset</a>
            <a class="btn btn-warning" role="button" href="#">Export CSV</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I also prefill the input fields with **min/max** dates with `value="{{ max_date|date:'Y-n-d' }}"`

Voilà !